# Search Listbox and return specific number of items defined in another field - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm running a search query that pulls the search string from one text box, then searches a listbox for the string and displays the results in a second listbox. I would like to define the number of items that it returns based on a second text box.  So far I am able to get all list items with be given string to show in the second box.  But I have yet to get it to limit the search to 1 item etc. The functional code I've used to show all results is:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    lstResults.Items.Clear()
    If txtSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then
        For index As Integer = 0 To lstCountries.Items.Count - 1
            Dim txt = lstCountries.Items(index).ToString()
            If txt.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                lstResults.Items.Add(txt)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

I've tried using `while txtnumber.text > 1 then` ahead of this but seem to have created a loop.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: by `specific number of items` do you mean the count of how many times something is in the list?

Comment: No I'm searching a list and the box that I need to integrate lets the user determine how man results are found.  For example if I was searching all states with search string 'Ma' if the box "number of states in search results" had the number 1 in it, then only Maryland would come up instead of Maryland and Massachusetts being returned

Comment: I hope that made sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource is going to have the final say on how many results there are.  If the user specifies 3 and there are only 2 in the source, thats all you will get.  Something like this will move the results from one to the other until the max is found:

```
Dim Max as integer = Convert.Toint32(txtNumber.Text)
Dim Count as integer = 0

lstResults.Items.Clear()

 For index As Integer = 0 To lstCountries.Items.Count - 1

        if lstCountries.Items(index).StartsWith(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            lstResults.Items.Add(lstCountries.Items(index))
            count += 1
        end if

        ' exit the loop if we found enough
        If count>= Max Then
            Exit For               
        End If
  Next
```

If the listbox just contains text (strings) then you do not need the ToString: `lstCountries.Items(index).StartsWith(strSearch)`.  Basically, you need to exit the loop once the user desired number have been found OR if you run out of data...if I understood right.  `while txtnumber.text > 1` would not work because textboxes contain strings not numerics (23 is not the same as "23").

Comment: The first textbox will have a search string to search a listbox, the second text box will have an integer which is the number of results that I want returned into the results list box.  will a query like the one you described work in that situation?

Comment: right, the code searches `lstCountries` to test if each item starts with `txtSearch.txt`.  that part is the same as in yours, I just changed the exit conditions (and used the search number limited as a numeric).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I knew there was something I was missing. I am curious what does the `convert.toint32` command do?

Comment: it converts the text in a text box to an integer ("23" ==> 23).  NORMALLY you should use Integer.TryParse on something like a TextBox.  If it contains "cat" that is not numeric, so TryParse will tell you it cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Cool thanks!! I have been stuck on that part of the last couple bits of this program for about  days.  Figured out the first part, but the search function I saved for last probably should start doing the hardest stuff first...

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ extensions would work well here as well:

```
    lstResults.Items.AddRange((From item In lstCountries.Items
                             Let strItem As String = item.ToString
                             Where strItem.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                             Select strItem).Take(Integer.Parse(txtnumber.Text)).ToArray)
```

This assumes that all your data has already been validated.

Comment: Well the data is preloaded through an array that pulls from a text file.. and then I have validation for the user entries built in. So this does work as well. Now to decide the best option.